# AngularDart data table

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, web-frontend

Could you please guide me to a resource where I can find a DataTable examples and materials to use it.
like this one: [https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview][1]
But these materials are only for Angular, I want a data table examples for AngularDart specifically. and I couldn't fine one In Angulardart gallery in there official website.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is off-topic on StackOverflow (looking for resources). See also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/312#issuecomment-435170824

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know that :(

Comment: More details in https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: this is a good alternative while waiting for google team open source their datatable component: https://github.com/skawa-universe/skawa_components